# Django channel jwt custom middelware passing data

Tags: websocket, jwt, middleware, django-channels

I'm trying to authenticate users using JWT through custom middleware for websocket communication. I'm sending the token from clientside by key, value and decode it from the serverside to get the user. But, when I try to access scope['user'] from comsumers, there is nothing. I want to know how I can pass on the scope['user'] to consumers. And I am not sure if this is a proper way to authenticate.

jwt_auth.py

```
@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(self, scope, decoded_data):
    user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=decoded_data['user_id'])
    return user

class JWTAuthMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
def populate_scope(self, scope):
    if b'token' not in scope['query_string']:
        raise ValueError(
            'JWTMiddleware cannot find token in scope.'
        )

async def resolve_scope(self, scope):
    token = parse_qs(scope['query_string'].decode('utf8'))['token'][0]
    # print('token -> ' + str(token))

    try:
        UntypedToken(token) # Verify JWT
        decoded_data = jwt_decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
        # print('decoded_data -> ' + str(decoded_data))

        scope['user'] = await get_user(self, scope, decoded_data)
        print('scope -> ' + str(scope))
        # return self.inner(scope)

    except (InvalidToken, TokenError) as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: So from your print statements, does it get the users successfully?

Comment: Yes, it does but, when I print it in the consumers, it's like I didn't add anything. :(